# jQuery stick div on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a top fixed div and then a main frame which contains two divs inside (left and right).
I want to make the right div stick just under the top bar on scroll.

I've put up what I have here:
http://jsfiddle.net/mhD9Y/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var window_top = 41 - $(window).scrollTop();
  var div_top = $('#stop_scroll').offset().top;
  if (window_top > div_top)
    $('#right').addClass('stick');
  else
    $('#right').removeClass('stick');

});



 .stick {
        position: fixed !important;
        top: 41px !important;z-index: 5 !important;    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    }
```

The thing is that the script doesn't kick in at all.

thanks

Comment: `var window_top = (41 - $(window).scrollTop());` made something happen, but it looks like crap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your code with window scroll.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
      var window_top = $(window).scrollTop() - 41;
      var div_top = $('.right').offset().top;
      if (window_top > 41) {
        if (!$('.right').is('.stick')) {
            $('.right').addClass('stick');
         }
      }  else
           $('.right').removeClass('stick');
    });
});
```

Either you change the id="right" to class="right"

OR

Change your css of the

.stick and add !important at the end of each attribute.

[DEMO on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhD9Y/12/)

Comment: `if (window_top > div_top) $('#right').toggleClass('stick');` should work assuming it is correctly set on load. Also for an operation like this which presumably will happen often, caching the elements would be wise.

Comment: Nothing happens, the #right div still scrolls past the top div.I'm using the two:<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: .stick {position: fixed;top: 41px;} , all what's in .stick

Comment: your id="right" have position as absolute.  your stick class doesnt have any effect.  Try changing the id="right " to class.

Comment: it sticks now, but on scroll the entire #right div is flashing ..fast

Comment: Awesome, can I add an easing when it changes class such that it will stick smoother? animate()?

Comment: I added:    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease; and it works

Comment: yes you can add as well as can do in js.  But css is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Script:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(window).scroll(function(){
        var window_top = $(window).scrollTop() - 41;
        var div_top = $('#stop_scroll').offset().top;
        console.log(window_top, div_top);
        if (window_top > div_top) {
             $('#right').addClass('stick');
        } else {
             $('#right').removeClass('stick');
        }
      });
    });
```

CSS:

```
    .stick {
        position: fixed !important;
        top: 41px !important;
    }
```